# Process only files with filename above a certain number

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a single directory full of millions of files with file names such as e.g.:

```
234.txt
235.txt
236.txt
```

I would like to work through the files with a name that has an integer prefix above a certain value, which is determined by the last file processed in a previous run and fetched from a database.

At the minute I have:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if int(re.split("\.",filename)[0]) > last_processed_id:
            <do some thing with file>
```

But I have hundreds of thousands of files, so this approach takes some time doing pointless work checking if the filename has been processed before. Is there a faster/better way to limit the files returned from os.walk() short of moving the files. once processed.

Comment: You could keep a record of those that were processed somewhere, perhaps in a log or SQLite DB.

Comment: Something has to do the comparison.  There are [shell methods](https://serverfault.com/questions/245087/find-files-their-name-is-smaller-or-greater-than-a-given-parameter) for doing the same but the comparison has to take place.

Comment: The "if" approach is correct - you can't escape it. What might save you sometime is, instead of `os.walk`  use the newer `os.scandir` call instead: it works best for a large number of files. `for file in os.scandir( directory): `

Comment: Unless there is some exploitable pattern in the data, this code must compare each filename. I've found that Perl tends to be faster than Python at this sort of task. You could consider rewriting this in Perl. Another option is to incorporate parallelism and split the work between several threads/processes.

Comment: Are you really sure this is the bottleneck?  A more plausible bottleneck to me would be using `re.split` to split on a literal `.`.  But without profiling that's just a guess.

Comment: Try to split the filename normally, `filename.split(".")[0]` instead of using re.

Comment: Profile the various approaches and find out.  Or if e.g. perl really is faster at this, write a script and parse its output.  And then bear in mind that the OS and hardware will have an effect.  Separately, for large jobs I would generate a list of filenames first and then iterate it with a progress bar: it doesn't run any faster, but if *feels* faster.

Comment: @2e0byo, you're absolutely correct. I just ran a quick timing experiment and `re.split()` takes 70x the time that `str.split()` does for this case. OP, I suggest the first thing you do is convert `re.split()` to `str.split()`.

Comment: @MichaelRuth or even use pathlib, which is pretty well engineered and might still be faster `int(p.name)`.  But re libraries are almost always slow; it's the tradeoff for being so flexible.  Glad I guessed right for once.

Comment: Also, you wrote it was a single dir, `os.listdir` is over 3 times faster than `os.walk`

Comment: @jsbueno FYI for [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk): "Changed in version 3.5: This function now calls os.scandir() instead of os.listdir(), making it faster by reducing the number of calls to os.stat()."

Comment: That is good - but `os.scandir` is still a bit ahead for a single directory because it will yield results as it goes, and not worry about scan all files first and just start iterating when all I/O is already done.